# Parallel versus series capacitor bank

Tags: power-supply, capacitor

[image]

### I DON'T WANT THE SOLUTION

I only want to know if the question said that the capacitor bank will be connected in SERIES with the motor. Will it have the same value of capacitive reactance?

Will a series connected capacitor bank serve the same purpose i.e., improving the power factor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will a series connected capacitor bank serve the same purpose i.e. improving the power factor?

It will improve the power factor. However, it will also deliver far too high a voltage to the motor, by resonating out some or all of the motor's inductive reactance.

That's why the question did not, and will not ever, ask about a series connected capacitor bank for power factor correction. That configuration is used, rarely, in other situations, but motor PF correction is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

“Determine the value of the capacitor to be connected in parallel”

No mention of series in that question.

Comment: Problem with English, and the notorious comma.  I believe the intent was, "I only want to know, what if the question said that the capacitor bank will be connected in SERIES..."